# IntelliJ asking to configure SDK and "run" won't appear in dropdown

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I am using the Lynda.com tutorial Gradle for Java Developers to learn Gradle. In the tutorial, he opens a new project with no template and copies a folder from the exercise files into the new project (I'm not sure if this is relevant to my problem). Without altering the Java class found in said folder, he right-clicks it from the sidebar and clicks "run" from the drop-down menu.

When I right-click it the class, "run" does not appear. Additionally, there is a message at the top of the text editor that says something along the lines of needing to configure an SDK. When I click on it, a pop-up saying something about "1.8" appears, as well as an "OK" button. When I choose run from the top menu, it simply brings up an "edit configuration" pop-up.

Can anyone explain to me why my layout is so different from the tutor's?

Edit: Now I see where my issue came from. The tutor was misleading with his "how to use the exercise files" video. He showed it to be as simple as clicking "open" on Intellij and opening the folder or dragging the folder to the intellij icon, without configuring an SDK. But in the tutorial video I was watching, he did something completely different by creating a new project and pasting a folder within the folder for the video, which actually ended up looking different from the template he used (His project was called GradleLab  and he copied the exercise files within it, while all the other exercise files include the GradleLab folder

Comment: yes, you need to configure sdk for any new java projects created in IntelliJ. check out this [link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-projects.html). It might be (being a tutor), he would have already set up sdk default in his ide/project.

Comment: What should I do if I am opening a project from an existing folder such as the exercises folder I downloaded?

Comment: still you need to set up sdk. without that IDE might not know what software it should be dealing with.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I should read more carefully. I was about to ask how to do so with an existing folder, buy your link goes over that under "Import a project". Thank you.